# LSTM returning only zeros (PyTorch)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

After succesfully implementing a LSTM "from scratch" based on linear layers, I decided to start using the existing LSTM class to make things easier and gain in performance.
But somehow when I try it, it only returns tensors full of zeros.
Here is the model :

```
class pytorchLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 1)

    def forward(self, input):
        out, hidden = self.lstm(input)
        out = self.softmax(out)
        return out, hidden
```

the input is a (1,1,60) tensor representing a one-hot encoded letter :

```
tensor([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
          0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
          0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
          0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]]])
```

and the models returns, invariably (I tried modifying the values inside of the input, but the result is always the same) :

```
tensor([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
           0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
           0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
           0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
           0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
           0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]],
        grad_fn=<LogSoftmaxBackward>)
```

Any idea where my mistake is and what I understood wrong about the LSTM class ?

Comment: shouldn't you provide hidden state and cell state (`h` and `c`) as inputs to `self.lstm` in the `forward` method?

Comment: @Shai As [documentation says](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM) the only needed thing is `inputs`, other will default to zero.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke for the first time step it makes sense. but what about the other time steps?

Comment: Depends on his use case; I assumed each sample is independent, and the sequence itself is self-contained example, hence it should start with `zeros` as per usual. If there is some kind of continuity between samples (e.g. first from first batch, second from first batch etc.) then sure, otherwise I see no reason for other values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing input of shape `(1,1,60)`, which can be described as `(sequence_length, batch_size, feature_size)`, where `feature_size` is binary.

I'm not sure why you are using `LogSoftmax` at all as it's discouraged and numerically unstable and it's advised to use [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss) taking logits straight out of your network, but that's not the problem here (might be later).

IIUC you are trying to predict another tensor of shape `(sequence_length, batch_size, feature_size)`, e.g. next letter in the word (or the same later as inputted, dunno).
You need to do `LogSoftmax(dim=2)` (not sure if `dim=-1` will work), currently you are softmaxing batch dimension.

Comment: Thanks ! I litteraly very  figured it out the moment you posted your answer. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Johncowk While we're at it, please accept one of the answers as solution if your problem is solved by it. And it seems your answer repeats exactly same points as mine, please don't make additional noise by repeating answers as it clutters the whole thing. :)

Comment: I'm a bit ashamed to admit it, but I don't know how to do it :/

Comment: You can click on the green tick under the upvotes/downvotes to accept an answer. To delete an answer (if it's yours), click on more under your answer and use delete. You can read [more about deleting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38937/how-to-delete-your-own-answer) or [here for accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow, enjoy your stay. :D